# How to migrate a js app that has no module to commonJs modules?

Tags: javascript, module, webpack

I am working on a big, valuable but old js app and while the code is quite clean, there is no concept of module there. The app is split in many files, and all are imported in index.html in "an order that works".

For many reasons, I would like to move the codebase to modules. *But* It really seems like a lot of work. And because of the dynamic nature of js, unresolved dependencies will be detected at runtime. So "lot of works" + "unreliable" makes it a dangerous endeavour.

What would be the best way to do that ? Is there any tools to assist me in this task (I am thinking of AST+dependency analyser) ?

Comment: start by moving it to one module, then pull out smaller pieces into sub-modules and replaceAll in the main module to update refs. if it recycles names a lot, then you might want to use unit tests (or sneaker tests) to watch your back.

Comment: You mean put everything into one file, right ? I see the value in that, but the app is so big, I am not sure it is practical.

Comment: it's not in one file already?

Comment: No, it is split in many files, and imported in the index.html *in an order that works*. I am adding this fact to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webpack has some tools available to address these situations. Check out the [exports loader](https://github.com/webpack/exports-loader) -- it exports a value (of your choice) from a module (file) that doesn't already export a value. That lets you more or less treat as if it were a module. Also check out the `imports-loader` (imports another file into a file, so that you can ensure the dependency is there at build time), and the other resources on that same page of the docs.